# useEffect executing after (?) the next command

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

A problem here :(

I have this code inside a functional component:

```js
  const [fact, setFact] = useState();
  
  useEffect( () => {

    async function startGetCatFact () {
      const {fact:factFromApi} = await getCatFact();
      setFact(factFromApi);
    }

    startGetCatFact();

    return 
  },[])
  
   
  const queryWords = fact.split(' ').slice(0, 3); //fact is not defined error
```

But there's a problem here that I can't understand:

When I execute this code I get an error that says that "fact" is not defined.
UseEffect should set my state fact and I should be able to use it after using the useEffect but I get the undefined all the time.
Pretty sure this is about asynchronous process and stuff but I can't find a solution.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Off topic: [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) has a second argument. instead of `fact.split(" ").slice(0, 3)` you can also write `fact.split(" ", 3)` and it will stop splitting when it has reached 3 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create your function outside of useEffect and call inside

```
const [fact, setFact] = useState();
const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true);
const startGetCatFact = async () => {
  const {fact:factFromApi} = await getCatFact();
  setFact(factFromApi);
  setLoading(false)
}

useEffect( () => {
    startGetCatFact();
  },[])

if(!loading){
  const queryWords = fact.split(' ').slice(0, 3);
}
```

so in that way u will fully control the loading stage.

Comment: Defenitely isLoading is a lifesaver, thank you so much !

Comment: Shouldn't be `loading` be true initially and after it is loaded the state `loading` be `false`?

Comment: oh yeah its vice verca. I was trying to type fast mb but I think Angel understand :D I will edit now thanks for notice

Answer (score 1):

it's very straightforward - when the code first gets uploaded, way before the useEffect runs - the 'fact' variable has no value, so it crashes.

the hook useEffect is basically the same as componentDidMount, so it only runs after the component mounted already - which means the code that uses the 'fact' variable first takes it's value from the initial state you're giving it when you're defining it.

to create an easy fix you can just give it a value in the use state and when the component will mount - that value will change to whatever you do set it to in the useEffect

Comment: For sure I should start initiating setState with some value. I'm still so newbie. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

replace this:

```js
const queryWords = fact.split(' ').slice(0, 3);
```

with:

```js
const queryWords = fact?.split(' ').slice(0, 3);
```

It(?) will to check variable on first render and when the variable is available it will use the variable

Comment: queryWord is not state. So it will not rerender when it is settled up. This is not the absolute solution.